# Linq with two tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I'working with project asp.net `MVC 4`
In my controller I need return a `Json` function.
this is my function:

```
public JsonResult DatosVehiculo(GridSettings grid, string IdReclamo){
...
List<cSindVehiculo> lDvehiculo = Servicio.RetornaDatos<cSindVehiculo>(ref Mensaje, "crdsis.sin_dvehiculo", dvehiculo.Where(), dvehiculo);
var count = DatosVehiculo.Count();
var data = DatosVehiculo.Skip((grid.PageIndex - 1) * grid.PageSize).Take(grid.PageSize).ToArray();
var jsonData = new{
    total = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)count / grid.PageSize),
    page = grid.PageIndex,
    records = count,
    rows = (
           from m in data
           select new {
                id = m.sdv_idreclamo,
                cell = new object[] {
                  m.sdv_idreclamo,
                  m.sdv_parpieza,
                  m.sdv_parcodclase
                }
           });.ToArray()
});
return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

this return in this format, for example:

```
sdv_idreclamo  sdv_parpieza  sdv_parcodclase
LP13000394         001           AC
LP13000394         002           CR
```

but in the grill don't understand the final user
I need that this display it:

```
sdv_idreclamo  sdv_parpieza  sdv_parcodclase
LP13000394     AMORTIGUADOR    ACCESORIOS
LP13000394    BOMBA DE ACEITE  CARROCERIA
```

But this description is in other table `"crdsis.cfg_parametros"` where:

```
cp_idparametro    cp_descparametro    cp_tipoparametro
0001              AMORTIGUADOR        PIEZA
0002              BOMBA DE ACEITE     PIEZA
AC                ACCESORIOS          CODCLASE
CR                CARROCERIA          CODCLASE
```

With a select I can obtain this:

```
SELECT
   crdsis.sin_dvehiculo.sdv_idreclamo,
   (select crdsis.cfg_parametros.cp_descparametro from crdsis.cfg_parametros where (crdsis.sin_dvehiculo.sdv_parpieza = crdsis.cfg_parametros.cp_idparametro) and crdsis.cfg_parametros.cp_tipoparametro = 'PIEZA') as sdv_parpieza,
   (select crdsis.cfg_parametros.cp_descparametro from crdsis.cfg_parametros where (crdsis.sin_dvehiculo.sdv_parcodclase = crdsis.cfg_parametros.cp_idparametro) and crdsis.cfg_parametros.cp_tipoparametro = 'CODCLASE') as sdv_parcodclase
from crdsis.sin_dvehiculo
where sdv_idreclamo = 'LP13000394'
```

I need modify my function `public JsonResult DatosVehiculo` to return this format.
How I can modify in `Linq`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe based on what you've posted that the LINQ statement belongs in:

`Servicio.RetornaDatos<cSindVehiculo>(ref Mensaje, "crdsis.sin_dvehiculo", dvehiculo.Where(), dvehiculo)`

Without more detail, it's hard to answer your question. You could certainly use the results of `ReturnoDatos` in a LINQ statement in your page, but I think that's the wrong layer for this functionality.

Comment: yes,  I have could resolve in other layer, Thanks showed me another vision of the problem